# How to get project path using docker

Tags: linux, docker

I have an Ubuntu machine, on which I've installed my Sails.JS(Node.JS) project.
I'm using docker on my Ubuntu machine, but unfortunately I'm not able to find the project location because it's using docker so I'm not able to get the exact project directory.

I've tried to use the following command

```
`sudo find . -name "*local.js*"`
```

It shows me that file inside the docker directory but there are lots of folders starting with some random alphanumeric text. All these folders contain my project's folder but I'm confused on which folder I can get my latest code.

Can anybody help me to find out the directory structure for my project?

Comment: please include source code, docker files ,... for having a better feedback

Comment: You're better off looking at the artifacts that built the image (its source tree, the Dockerfile, ...) than trying to dig around in a running container.  It will probably be obvious from the Dockerfile where the project is being installed, and if you need to make changes, you should be making them at that level and rebuilding the image anyways.

Answer (score 4):

You are searching files in your host machine which is showing your files in  the docker volumes at `/var/lib/docker`.

You have to go inside docker then you need to search it.

1. Get docker name or id by running command

   ```
   docker ps

   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
   aa6f45710063        mydockerimage   "/start.sh"         3 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        1337/tcp            sailsjs_app
   ```
2. go inside docker using command

   ```
   docker exec -it containername_or_ID /bin/bash

   example:
   docker exec -it aa6f45710063 /bin/bash
   ```
3. Now your inside docker container. you can search your file in it.

   ```
   find . -name "*local.js*"
   ```
4. once your work is done. You can exit from container by running command

   ```
   exit
   ```

Comment: i run the "docker exec -it containername_or_ID /bin/bash" command and able to view my project there. Can you please give some idea to get this project on my local Linux machine.

Comment: If you want to copy the code in local from your instance then use command `docker cp container_name_or_id:/path_of_files . `

Comment: Did you know how to get whole project src from container and then edit ind get back intro container ?